# wordpress multi instance cloud hosting

Tags: mysql, wordpress, cloud, replication, multiple-instances

I've been looking at several of the big cloud providers Google, AWS, Azure and I'm trying to figure out the best approach and what provider might be the most cost effective when doing so.  What I'm looking to do is spin up a WP instance for www.mydomain.com in the US (master), EU, Asia and potential more as traffic grows so that I can load balance across regions. I know that I can spin up different instances which all point back to 1 master DB (mysql) but obviously that still creates a bottle neck.

What is the best way to create a replicated DB across all instances?  Does one or all of these cloud providers set this up quickly and easily?  Are there any articles out there that can point me to how to set this up?

Comment: So you want a DB in each region that you can write to?

Comment: I'm not sure your question is programming related and am voting to close as such (see [faq])... but there are other sites on the network that may be suitable (see footer).  Anyway the best is to check the site FAQ and browse related questions before asking.